# Images Processing/JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a javascript program that modifies  an image by putting three vertical stripes on it. A red stripe on the left one third, a green stripe in the middle and a blue stripe on the right one third.

Here is the algorithm that i am trying to implement:
1. Start with the image you want to change.

2. Figure out the width of the image.
3. For each pixel in the image:
   Get the x-coordinate for that pixel
   If the pixel’s x-coordinate is less than one-third of the image’s width, set the pixel’s red value to 255.
   If the pixel’s x-coordinate is between one-third and two-thirds of the image’s width, set the pixel’s green value to 255.
   If the pixel’s x-coordinate is more than two-thirds of the image’s width, set the pixel’s blue value to 255.
4. Print the image.

   ```
   var MyImage = new SimpleImage("hilton.jpg");
   var ImgWidth = MyImage.getWidth();

   for (var pix of MyImage.values()){
       var Xcoordinate = pix.getX();
       var Ycoordinate = pix.getY();
       if (Xcoordinate < ImgWidth/3){
           pix.setRed(255);
       }

       else if (ImgWidth/3< Xcoordinate < ImgWidth/2){
           pix.setGreen(255);
       }

       else{ 
           Xcoordinate > ImgWidth/3;
           pix.setBlue(255);
       }
   }
   print(MyImage);
   ```

The red strip is coming out as expected but the green stripe is occupying the rest of the image and the blue doesn't appear at all. No error message.

Comment: If you have a partially working implementation, please share actual code, preferably in a [mcve] using a Stack Snippet (The `[<>]` button on the toolbar)

Comment: Your sample code has `setRed()`, but I don't see `setGreen()` or `setBlue()`

Answer (score 1):

I think your test for the green strip doesn't do what you want it to:

```
ImgWidth/3< Xcoordinate < ImgWidth/2
```

You can't chain the boolean operators that way. Probably it should be:

```
ImgWidth / 3 < Xcoordinate && Xcoordinate < ImgWidth / 2
```

Also this line is redundant:

```
Xcoordinate > ImgWidth/3;
```

You are not assigning the result to any variable.

Comment: And `ImgWidth / 3 && ImgWidth / 2` will get a 1/3 : 1/1.5 : 1/4.5 ratio of colors, so it should be `ImgWidth / 3 && ImgWidth*2/3` ( desirable 1/3:1/3:1/3 ratio )

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much to SkilGG. I just reviewed my test for the green strip and deleted the redundant line in the else clause. Came up with those lines and my code is now working.

```
    var MyImage = new 
    SimpleImage("hilton.jpg");
    var ImgWidth = MyImage.getWidth();

    for (var pix of MyImage.values()){
        var Xcoordinate = pix.getX();
        if (Xcoordinate < ImgWidth/3){
            pix.setRed(255);
        }

        else if (Xcoordinate < 2*ImgWidth/3){
            pix.setGreen(255);
        }

        else{ 
            pix.setBlue(255);
        }
    }
    print(MyImage);
```